# How to retrieve a word from list 01 not present in list 02

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to retrieve the word from listPRO who are not present in listREA.

I have 2 list :

| listPRO | listREA |
| --- | --- |
| ORSAY | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
| REMBRANDT_AMSTERDAM | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
| OMAN | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
| ORSAY | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | KREFELD_MOBILES STADTMUSEUM |
|  | REMBRANDT_AMSTERDAM |
|  | REMBRANDT_AMSTERDAM |
|  | REMBRANDT_AMSTERDAM |
|  | ORSAY |
|  | ORSAY |
|  | ORSAY |
|  | ORSAY |
|  | ORSAY |

So here, I would like to retrieve the word "OMAN".

So far, I have been able to create the list from my spreadsheets and get the info I need. But now, how the comparison should look alike ?

as I was not able to find the word missing, I have first try to find the word in common with this code but it fails... I don't know if it was a good start...

```
  for (i = 0; i < listePRO.length; i++) {
      //Logger.log(listePRO[i][0])

      for (j = 0; j < listeREA.length; j++) {
      //Logger.log(listeREA[j][29])
        if (listeREA[j][29] === listePRO[i][0]) {
            }
        RESULTsheet.getRange(1+ [i],5).setValue(listePRO[i][0])
 
      }
    }
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: take a look at indexOf() method of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula that can help you with this:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0)))
```

[image]

**Update:**

You can use a [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) with Apps Script to filter the values that are missing in `listPRO` that are available in `listREA`.

```
function compareArray() {
  let listREA = [array]
  let listPRO = [array]

  let result_x = listPRO.filter(function (x) {
    return !listREA.includes(x);
  })

  console.log(result_x)

}
```

The result:

[image: apps script]

**Update:**

I am not sure where you are getting your columns, I took them from Google Sheets since it was easier for the sample. I created an independent function just to select the column you want to work with.

```
function compareList() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_sheet').getSheetByName('Sheet4')

  let listREA = sheet.getRange('J3:N21').getValues();
  let listPRO = sheet.getRange('P3:S6').getValues();

  // The column you want from listPRO
  listPRO_column = 0;
  // The column you want from listREA
  listREA_column = 4;

  //Pass the variables to the new function to create the new array 
  let new_listPRO = createArray(listPRO, listPRO_column);
  let new_listREA = createArray(listREA, listREA_column);

  //using the last filter with the new information 

  let result_x = new_listPRO.filter(function (x) {
    return !new_listREA.includes(x);
  })
}


// New function to create a new array 
// Extracting just the column you want to work on 

function createArray(array, column) {
  let arrayLength = array.length;
  let arrayValues = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    arrayValues.push(array[i][column])
  }
  return arrayValues
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but I was talking about a script solution, because thoose 2 list doesn't really exist anywhere, they are created by filters in a script !

Comment: @antho2B, I will update with a script in a moment.

Comment: it works great ! thanks ! but considering that my ListREA and ListPro both have multiple column, how can get only column number 0 for listPro and column number 29 for listREA ? I have try this   ``` for (i = 0; i < listePRO.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < listeREA.length; j++) {
      listePROname = listePRO[i][0];
      listeREAname = listeREA[j][29]
       let result_x = listePROname.filter(function (x) {
          return !listeREAname.includes(x);
        })
console.log(result_x)}}``` but it tell me : TypeError: listePROname.filter is not a function

Comment: @antho2B, I will update the answer once for in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
function in1NotIn2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const list2 = sh.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  const ws = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e).filter(e => !~list2.indexOf(e))
  Logger.log(ws);
}

Execution log
3:15:40 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:15:40 PM  Info    [OMAN]
3:15:42 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```